# Intellij-Idea Linux Multi User Install <No SDK>?

Tags: linux, java, intellij-idea

Intellij Idea has been installed into /opt and /opt/idea-IC/bin/idea.sh was run via sudo from which point a desktop entry was created for all users.

When running sudo ./idea.sh and I attempt to create a new project I'm offered the option to choose for the Project SDK - 11 (java version "1.8.0_202")

Then running idea as a user from my desktop, the Project SDK offered is - <No SDK>

Is there a way for the regular users to see the option as presented to root.  This is meant to be a multi-user install.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just make the folder visible to non-root users and then allow each user to configure their environment?

Comment: All users have read/execute access for /opt/idea-IC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide a little more context, my environment is an Amazon Linux Workspace.

The solution was to install java-11-openjdk-jmods

```
sudo yum install java-11-openjdk-jmods
```